# Submit a form with a file and mail that as an attachment using PHP

Tags: php, email, message, attachment

I'm new to php and I try to set up a submission form. I want to be able to upload a file and attach the file and send it with my message. I can receive all messages but no file is received. I use the nl2br function for the message. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `enctype` of the form? You need to do this in order to send files with forms.

Somce code of yours would be a great help in understanding problem, but my guess is you didn't specified `enctype`. It should look similar to this:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no i did not define enctype. I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'm going to add it right now

Answer (score 0):

In HTML add to `<form>` the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Then, for uploading files : `<input type="file" name="myfile" />`

Then in PHP:

Instead of going for direct mailing using the PHP `mail()` function, use `PHPMailer`. It'll make it all quite easy for you, handling all that by itself. All you need to do will be a few function calls and it's done.

Here's a sample:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "An HTML Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hello, <b>my friend</b>! \n\n This message uses HTML entities!";

?>
```

For a complete tutorial, visit http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial

EDIT: Have a look here, check the video series: http://bit.ly/1Ekgzel

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is this even related?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This tutorial seems to be what I need. I can send any message but the problem is with my attachment

Comment: @Forien I actually had misunderstood the question because of the OP's mentioning "being new to PHP". I took it that he wasn't able to send the attachments along with the email. I have corrected it, hopefully.

Comment: @user3451793 Glad I could be of help.

Comment: I mean i do not want sb to give me a raw code, i need tutorials cause first i want to learn and then to do my job

Comment: @user3451793 then google as much as possible, and when you are stuck, post your problem here on StackOverflow (possibly with the code related to the problem) and we (community) will try to help :)

Comment: @Afaan yes my problem is with the attachment. I can send and receive any message. This part works like a charm

Comment: @Forien I dont know why but I cannot paste my code. I googled already and i played with pear but no result.

Comment: @user3451793 Check the video series link, its a google search page with a link to a video series explaining in detail PHPMailer (with attachments).